# How are beta site statistics calculated?

Tags: bug, status-completed, statistics, beta-sites

How are the statistics calculated?

Currently at [Puzzling beta](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com) I see:

> Site Stats
>
> 203   questions
>   357   answers
>   100%  answered
>   565   users
>   262   visitors/day

There are 8 questions with 0 answers: [link](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/unanswered)

So 195 questions out of 203 are answered, that gives 96%, not 100%. Is it a bug?

Comment: Caching, surely.

Comment: Probably a case of http://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: Could you elaborate, please? How cache can lead to such a thing if unanswered questions were asked a long time ago?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The site stats use the public API's [info method](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/info), which had a bug (related to [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233987/is-the-automatic-question-deletion-routine-broken)). This bug [is fixed now](http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/info?site=puzzling). The beta site stats widget in the sidebar is cached for an hour, so within at most 60 minutes, it should show correct data as well.